# Chrome bug? :hover style being ignored

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium

The `:hover` effect doesn't get applied properly sometimes. 
I noticed it in Chrome 44 or Chrome 45, both Mac and Windows.

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/f5pfoo83/7/)

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Go here: http://jsfiddle.net/f5pfoo83/7/
2. Move the mouse hover the link multiple times
3. Move it again after the transition is applied or while it takes place

There's [an issue opened at chromium issues](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=525213) about it and multiple users reported it.

Comment: Doesn't seem a problem at my end. Using ChromeOS with `Chrome 45` latest stable build.

Comment: I just tested in `Chrome 44` and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you check the videos provided in the issue at chromium forum? I still have the problem in `45.0.2454.99 m`